# How can I change the default Terminal font?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, themes, fonts

No more to it, I can't seem to find any kind of Options or properties in the Terminal app. Is there a way to change the default font?

Comment: All tips here are great!
Does anyone know to enable the font ligature for the FiraCode font on the terminal?

Comment: <-- has the same question as  @JoãoMarques

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To change font in the Terminal you need `dconf-editor`. Install it, if you haven't done so:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Run it and go to path `org` > `gnome` > `desktop` > `interface` > `monospace-font-name`.

[image]

Enter name of desired font and font size. For example `Anonymous Pro 11`.

You can also [use the command in Terminal](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1153) instead of the `dconf-editor`.

Answer (score 31):

To change the font of *just* the terminal (pantheon-terminal), you can use the `dconf-editor` (requires an install) or the `gsettings` command. Edit the `font` property in the `org.pantheon.terminal.settings` schema. For example:

```
$ gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings font 'FreeMono 10'
```

You will have to close and reopen the terminal for the changes to take effect.

Comment: most simplest way :)

Comment: Is there a way to only update font-size but not font-family?

Comment: you could try a regex with sed that only replaces the trailing number based on the current value of the setting

Answer (score 7):

For versions 5.0 above:

```
 gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings font 'FiraCode 10'
```

Comment: This works with Elementary 6 Odin.

Answer (score 5):

If you already havent, install elementary-tweaks (For elementary freya):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

Then go to `System Settings` > `Tweaks` > `Fonts` and select the Monospace Font you want as well as its size. You can customize many other things as well from here.

[image]

Comment: It's not available for Loki

Comment: +1 Changing the monospace font here was the only way the font looked as it should for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do many customizations using `elementary-tweaks` switchboard plugin. But the older repository is not maintained by the original author anymore. Fortunately it's been forked by some other devs and the source is available in Github. Here is the project link https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks

It also has a PPA. So, add the ppa and update-index using this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks && sudo apt-get update
```

and install it using this

```
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

Logout and login again. You'll find the tweak item in **System Settings**. Alternatively you can just kill the `wingpanel` and start it again.